# The error of use NoSQL Manager for MongoDB tool

Tags: mongodb

i have a problem needs to help.
here it is!
when i use NoSQL Manager for MongoDB connects my localhost. it shows successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGe0y.png)

but when i open a certain database. an error shows bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrtSr.png)

how can i fix the problem,thanks.

Comment: the detail of the error is :The GuidRepresentation for the reader is CSharpLegacy, which requires the binary sub type to be UuidLegacy, not UuidStandard.

Comment: Screenshots generally are not helpful to questions here, and especially where the error is truncated. It would seem more likely though that the product is using an older library which is no longer supported for modern MongoDB API. Please also edit your question rather than posting comments with details. This is not a "discussion thrread", so your "question" is where all the detail goes instead.